# magento EE 2 Campaign / Promo deactivate

Tags: promotions, magento2-enterprise

I want to deactivate particular campaign in staging dashboard in Magento EE 2.1.6  version. 
Please suggest.

Comment: can you check https://belvg.com/blog/coupons-in-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS I checked for this, There is no such option in Magento EE, We can do some DB operations to achieve this solution.

Comment: I am having the same issue with Magento EE 2.1.5. What tables store the campaign info? How did you solve the problem?